# How do I make a gate diagram for \$a'c'+abc+ac'\$?

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, logic-gates

[image: gate diagram]

I have checked with the program [Logic Friday](https://logic-friday.software.informer.com/1.1/) and it checked the shown gate diagram, which showed me another result and came with this gate diagram:

[image]

Is this the correct answer?

Comment: No, it's far too complex. Hint: what does a'c' + ac' equal?

Comment: we can check this just as well as you can. You're asking this for a reason – where does your doubt arise from?

Comment: @DaveTweed well it can still be correct if its not as simple as possible (or sensible).

Comment: I used logic friday to check and it gave me another result.

Comment: I have no idea what that is, but assuming it's a probably infallible program, your circuit  is wrong. What's the question then?

Comment: How do I make a correct circuit?

Comment: That's not the question you're asking in your question post, though. So, please edit the question post, saying that you already checked (explain how you did that), and that it's not the correct circuit according to your check. Explain what you did to find the error. Explain why you're stuck designing it correctly.

Comment: Do both circuits give the same results? [Logic Friday](https://logic-friday.software.informer.com/1.1/) probably did some minimization, which what I was alluding to above.

Comment: (remark: I don't think this is not what's happening here, but engineers really dislike when they feel "baited" by bait-and-switch questions; it's always a good idea to have a very good understanding of what you *actually* want to ask.)

Comment: I edited it. Is it more obvious now?

Comment: @DaveTweed If no minimization was made would it then be correct?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Can you answer?

Comment: @InvulnerableImmortal I already told you, you can check this just as well as we can.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This logic gate diagram is correct and shows the gate diagram for a'c'+abc+ac'.